# How to disable "This workbook contains macros"

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, macros

This prompt comes up each time I open a file which I trust, is there a way to disable it permanently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding the workbook to a trusted location will stop this message from appearing.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-HA010354311.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342232

Answer (score 0):

Preference | Security | Macro Security

uncheck 'Warn before...'